# If a control class uses a method from another class, how do we model the association?

Tags: uml, class-diagram

If a control class uses a method from another class, how do we model the association?

For example, if I have a `User` class and a `PortalController` class that allows users to add or delete another user, how do I model the association in UML?

I suppose `User` should be a dependency for `PortalController` since it uses methods from `User` to create a new user.

```
User <--- PortalController
```

But a user would also be the one using the `PortalController`, so there should be another association:

```
       uses
User --------> PortalController
```

Should I draw two arrows?

Comment: For me, you will clearly have PortalController using User but why User would use PortalController !?

Comment: For example, a user logs in to the online portal to make changes?

Comment: This would implied a dependency cycle which is never good. Are you sure that the User modified by the PortalController and the User using the PotalController are the same concepts? For me the first seems to be a person and the second the session of a connected person..

Comment: In that case would a more accurate relation be a dependency -- where User is a dependency of PortalController?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a class A uses a method from another class B, you should model it as a Usage dependency from A to B depicted below [image]

Now I am pretty sure that you mix two differents User.

When you said that you PortalController is able to manage a set of User, you are dealing with the structure/implementation of your system so it seems normal to have two classes.

When you said that a User logs to your system, you are dealing with the use case of your system. So in this case the User would be an actor using your system.

Does it help?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should extract the responsibility of the creation of the user from the user class into another class (e.g. a UserFactory). And as Red Beard already remarked, your design seems to overlay two different concepts of "User".

In that case you would have:

```
              uses
UserSession --------> PortalController

UserSession --------> User

                    uses
PortalController  --------> UserFactory

PortalController  --------> User

           instantiates
UserFactory --------> User
```